# how to explain the word "that" used in this sentence

Tags: relative-clauses

> Only, she began to be afraid of the ghastly white tombstones, that peculiar loathsome whiteness of carrara marble, detestable as false teeth, which stuck up on the hillside under tevershall church, and which she saw with such grim painfulness from the park.

Comment: Where's this from? It could do with some punctuation IMO including a comma before *that*. The word is introducing a clause that describes the white tombstones just mentioned.

Comment: Just your usual determiner. Nothing special. Used that way in a great many languages, too.

Comment: From *Lady Chatterley's Lover*, by D.H. Lawrence. The only grammatical question I see is whether it should be *that* or *those*.

Comment: I bet you’re having trouble with understanding the actual syntax involved here, which is one of nouns in apposition.

Comment: It does seem like _those_ would be more in agreement with the antecedent. It seems like it's switching mid-sentence to treating all the tombstones in a cemetary as a collective.

Comment: @Barmar It's a demonstrative determiner; as such, it has no antecedent and must agree in number with the noun it determines. _Whiteness_, the head noun, is singular; therefore _that_ must be singular also. The fact that multiple tombstones are being described as one whiteness is not really strange to me. Just consider it a semi-elliptical way of saying “that loathsome expanse of white marble”. Similarly, a communist might well speak of “the workers, that most noble and worthy class of people” _vel sim_.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I see what you mean. I was thinking it could be something like _those peculiar, loathsome whitenesses..._. But that doesn't scan well, and is less poetic sounding.

Comment: @Peter, Barmar: I don't see how ***those*** could be parsed in this context, where ***that*** references the *peculiar loathsome] **whiteness***.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't a clause connector, it's more of a reference on the feeling which the marble colouring brings.

Eg.

That feeling you get when you hear a sound in your house in the middle of the night.

Answer (score 0):

In the cited excerpt, the author adjusts the focus of the narrative in midsentence, from "the ghastly white tombstones" to "that peculiar loathsome whiteness" of the marble from which the tombstones are carved. The substance of the sentence wouldn't change if we reworded the first part of the sentence as follows:

> Only, she began to be afraid of the ghastly white tombstones, and in particular of the peculiar loathsome whiteness of the carrara marble...

Presumably the author has opted to use *that* instead of *the* in the original version of the sentence in order to emphasize a familiarity with the "peculiar loathsome whiteness" that has captured the narrator's (and the character's) attention.

As Janus Bahs Jacquet's comment above explains, the *that* attaches forward to the later singular noun that it modifies ("whiteness") rather than backward to the earlier plural noun ("tombstones") that immediately precedes it. For this reason, *that* (not *those*) is the correct demonstrative determiner to use, given that the author had chosen to use such a determiner instead of using a simple definite article ("the").